# How do I layout, and close this dialogbox in PyQt?

Tags: python, user-interface, pyqt, pyqt5

I'm writing a Flash Card application using Python and PyQt and I have a problem with dialogboxes. First, here's the section of my code which concerns the aforementioned dialogbox:

```
def openFile(self):
    dialog = QDialog()
    dialog.setGeometry(200, 100, 50, 100)

    list = QListWidget(dialog)
    for file in files:
        list.addItem(file.replace('.flashcard', ''))

    list.itemClicked.connect(self.listClicked)

    dialog.exec_()

def listClicked(self, item):


    file_to_read = item.text() + '.flashcard'
    self.flashcard_list = FlashCard.read_card(file_to_read)

    self.front_text.clear()
    self.back_text.clear()
    self.front_text.insertPlainText(self.flashcard_list[0].front)
    self.back_text.insertPlainText(self.flashcard_list[0].back)
```

Although I'm using PyCharm, I can't actually debug the code since deubgging these sorts of applications is beyond my skill level. That's why I don't know why when I add codes like `dialog.setLayout(layout)` to the script, it won't run and it doesn't produce any errors. Also, I would like to know how to close this dialogbox since if I change the dialog to `self.dialog` to carry it over to another function, the code won't run, again, without producing any errors.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Can you show the code that won't run?  You're not adding the `QListWidget` to the dialog in this example.